# Ubuntu Server shows that I am running out of disk space, but I can't figure out where it is being used

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, disk-space, ubuntu-server, du

I am showing that I am running out of disk space and I am having trouble uploading, but I can't figure out where the disk space is being used. I am supposed to have 19 gigabytes, but it looks like only around 2.2 gigs is available. I have posted the results of the `df` and `du` commands below.

**root@ubuntu:/# df -h**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       19G  2.1G  111M  96% /
none            256M  8.0K  256M   1% /dev
overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
none             52M 1000K   51M   2% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            256M     0  256M   0% /run/shm
```

**root@ubuntu:/# du . -h --max-depth=1**

```
12K     ./srv
5.3M    ./bin
4.0K    ./media
0       ./tmp
273M    ./var
1000K   ./run
15M     ./lib
8.0K    ./dev
56K     ./root
16M     ./etc
4.0K    ./opt
du: cannot access `./proc/22716/task/22716/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/22716/task/22716/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/22716/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/22716/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       ./proc
0       ./sys
4.0K    ./boot
4.0K    ./selinux
567M    ./usr
5.1M    ./sbin
1.3G    ./home
4.0K    ./mnt
2.1G    .
```

Comment: Is this a VPS of some kind?

Comment: Psst!  M. Schwartz.  It's `/dev/simfs` so it's OpenVZ and has [these characteristics](http://openvz.org/Disk_quota,_df_and_stat_weird_behaviour).

Comment: It is a VPS. Thanks for the information JdeBP, but I only get the jest of that article. Any suggestions on things I should look into?

Comment: I'm hoping that someone will take that info and run with it to create an answer.  I don't have the time to.  It's "[gist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gist#English)", by the way.